# fs isSymbolicLink() not working in docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, ubuntu

In my project, I have some directories, which are symbolically linked to other directories using `ln -s -f`.

Here is a sample output of `ls -lah` in the root directory of my project

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 someuser someuser   23 Jan 13 14:03 Geo -> /CodeBase/Geo/Admin/`

I run my project using a custom docker image with certain volumes using docker-compose and here is the same directory inside my container using `ls -lah`

`drwxrwxrwx 10 node node 4.0K Jan 16 07:07 Geo`

in my project, I need to know which files are symbolically linked, I'm usinc fs to figure this out, here is the code that I'm using:

```
const stats = fs.statSync(path)
console.log(stats.isSymbolicLink());
```

this code runs inside the container and the path is `./src/Geo/CityDivision/Field.jsx`

I want to know why this always returns false even though these files are indeed symbolic links. Is it because I'm checking the files within the directory or is it because of the docker volumes or any other particular reasons that I'm not aware of?

Comment: That `ls -l` output indicates that `Geo` is a directory (`d`) in the container, not a link (the line would start with `l`).

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand, I was just wondering why is that so? and why there is no trace of these files/directories being symbolic links inside the container. maybe I didn't make that clear in my question, thanks anyways

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  How does the content get into the container filesystem?